# i dont know how to get ubuntu software i keep getting a message that it can not find it

Tags: 16.04, release-management

i do not have the Ubuntu software manager on my system i have tried using the terminal to get it using the codes but it wont let me i keep getting the same message like try another way what other way can i do this

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install it?

Comment: im using xenial ubuntu i did the update and upgrade and i insalled it using chrome os using developer mode using crosh

Answer (score 0):

To install the Ubuntu Software package, open a terminal and paste

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Type your password and hit enter.

Comment: i did that and it keeps saying but its not going to be installed

Comment: Edit your question and include the full output from the command. This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a year and a half ago while running 16.04. Software Centre disappeared and I searched for a solution for days. Nothing worked so I finally gave up and simply upgraded to 17.10. If you can find a fix, great otherwise I recommend upgrading to 19.04 as it is leaner and faster than previous versions and many long awaited changes have been made. I know it is probably overkill, but you will get "Ubuntu Software" which is the new "Software Centre"

To do this:

1. Open "Software & Updates" click on the Updates tab, and ensure "For any new version" is selected at the bottom.
2. Run "Software Updater". After updating all your applications, you will have the option to upgrade to a newer version.
3. Repeat step 2 until your operating system is up-to-date.

You may wish to stop at version 18.04, which is the latest LTS (long-term support) version. In that case, once you have installed 18.04, you can repeat step 1 and change the Notification option to "For long-term support versions"

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I had the same problem and wasted days trying to get my software centre back to no avail. This is just a recommendation, and I can assure you that the software centre will be back.

Comment: btw, thanks for downgrading someone who is only trying to help, and actually gave a viable solution to his problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that you take this as an attack on you. It's not. I asked how this solved the question, and I downvoted it. I still believe "upgrade" is not a very good answer, when *basic* functionality in a still supported Ubuntu release is not working. It may be valid in some cases, where hardware support is missing, or as an last resort if the problem can't easily be resolved in other ways. At the moment we hardly know what the problem is. At the very least, you should explain *why* you believe this to be a good answer.

Comment: I didn't take it as an attack. I took it as you being a prick. And I did make it clear that for me at least it was a last resort, since I never found a proper solution. Oh wait... what's this? It's been 6 months and still no "good" answer.

Comment: I still cannot see any reason for you to take this view. I'm sorry that you see me as a prick, for pointing this out, but I still stand by my comment, and your assumptions about me *downgrading* you by asking a fair and open question seems overreacting. I'm not gonna spend more time on this discussion anyway.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding. Did you down-vote my response?

Comment: No. I left a comment. Your answer has not been downvoted by anyone as far as I can see...

Comment: You say it yourself you downvoted it in your second comment. To answer your question though, my answer may not be elegant, but does answer his question: "What other way can do this?" (get ubuntu software back) If he upgrades he'll get it back AND have a better OS, without having to keep trolling the forums or expending a lot of effort and time. I solved the exact same problem he has the way I spelled out, and I have exactly zero regrets that I did.